# Can I change the default auto-generated suffix a Visual Studio 2010 run-time T4 text template's outputted cs file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4, texttemplate

I am using a run-time T4 Text Template. I wish for the preprocessor generated C# file to have an output extension of .tt.cs, however, by default, it only has an extension of .cs. If this were a design-time text template, I could add an output extension directive to enforce this behaviour. However, it appears that such directives don't have any affect on run-time templates. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this with run-time templates?

```
<#@ output extension=".tt.cs" #>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no trivial way, but it can be done.

First create your own single file generator, derived from TemplatePreprocessor in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplationg.VSHost.10.0.dll and register it with Visual Studio.

Then overide ProcessTemplate() and after calling the base implementation, call SetFileExtension with whatever extension you want.

It's a lot of work though for such a small change.

Comment: There we go. Sounds like @GarethJ knows what he's talking about better than me.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I agree that it sounds lke a lot of work for such a small change. I'm going to take your word for it that your method works. I'm also going to mark your answer as the solution, and move on from caring about this detail. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following at this [link](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/). Might be of use to you as he shows how to set the .cs using a Preprocessed Template but only if you are calling the template from within another template. Haven't found anything showing it's possible if run from in the C# or VB code.

*The <#@ output #> directive appears to have no effect on preprocessed templates. No error is generated when a preprocessed template contains this directive. The hosting application is responsible for changing the extension of the output file.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It appears that you understood my question, but unfortunately, your solution doesn't appear to work for run-time text templates - only design time text templates. I'll rephrase the question to hopefully improve clarity.